# python sorting list between 1 and the lists

Tags: python, sorting

How can i sort the list between [1]

```
get = ([4, 5, 2], [1], [3])

after = ([1,2,3])
```

- if 1 is 1 greater than which is two add two to the list
- if 2 is 1 greater than which is 3 add 3 to the list
- but 5 is not greater so don't add 5

example:

```
get = ([5, 6, 4], [1], [2, 3])

after = ([1,2,3,4])
```

how can you do this without doing something complex?

Comment: Please rephrase your question - this doesn't make any sense as it stands...

Comment: Ya I agree, I can't understand anything from the question, please rephrase the question

Comment: Context would help. What do you plan on doing with the `after` list? Where is the `get` list coming from?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to look for the smallest number in each list in get, see how many numbers are in sorted order starting from the lowest one, and add them sorted to the results list? Just makes little sense to me, but that would be in line with the examples...

Comment: What is this! I wonder what Chris understood when he edited this...

Comment: @deadcode There were several lines separated only by one newline character, I assumed OP was just unfamiliar with stackoverflow markdown and wanted them shown on three separate lines, so all I did was insert an asterisk at the beginning of each line in hopes that the result would better reflect the author's intent.

Comment: _How do you do this without doing anything to complex?_ seems to be OP's catchphrase. Maybe they should just make it their handle.

Answer (score 1):

is it complex?:

```
get = ([5, 6, 4], [1], [2, 3])
after=[]
for i in get:
    for j in i: after.append(j)
after.sort()
print(after)
```